# Meaning of "raw proof"

Tags: word-usage

I read some sentences including "raw proof" but I can't find out what it means.

> She is giving raw proof that we are slaves to our society.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such a brief excerpt it is difficult to say exactly what is meant, but three possibilities spring to mind:

- In many disciplines it is common to speak of "raw" data: the numbers or facts exactly as they arrive, before they are subjected to ordering and analysis. Your sentence might mean that  "her" experience (or story, or whatever "she" provides) is a bare anecdote which even before critical analysis provides "proof that we are slaves to our society".
- "Raw" is also used figuratively to mean "unadorned" or "not made pretty", so the author might mean that "her" story, even in the crude form in which she told it, without literary craft, provides the "proof".
- "Raw" is also used figuratively of wounds to mean that the living flesh is exposed and acutely sensitive. In this sense we also speak of "raw" nerves. And this sense of sensitivity is sometimes extended to mean that an event or story is very painful.

In addition, there is also the possibility that the word "raw" is simply being misused. I observe that the verb in your sentence is cast in the progressive form, which is not ordinary English idiom. So it is possible that its author is not a native speaker of English, and has used "raw" in a sense which is natural in another language, but not in English.

In any case, "raw proof" is not an expression whose meaning is immediately apparent, at least to me. Google tells me that this is the name of a band, and a term of art in numismatics, and that "raw proof block" is an expression in theorem-proving software; but I doubt that any of these are what is intended here.

Comment: I like #2. "Unprocessed" & "unadorned". It's one thing to say that a certain percentage of American kids, e.g., go to bed hungry & quite another to show a video of a hungry kid crying itself to sleep while the kid's helpless, foodless mother looks on in despair. Or to say that 3 people were decapitated & quite another to show the gory photos of the heads & headless bodies. "Not pretty" at all. Raw in that sense. Or in the sense of watching [Jimmy Swaggert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Swaggart) do his thing with prostitutes on a webcam rather than watching pretty Debbie do Dallas.